# Create RSQLite from csv containing umlauts - then read in using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rsqlite

I have a large csv file containing umlauts (Ä/Ö) that I need to transform to a RSQLite database to analyse in parts using dplyr. However, when I read in data from the database, the umlauts do not reproduce correctly. Ä becomes `<c4>` and Ö becomes `<d6>`. `read.csv`reproduces the umlauts correctly.

```
# Create test data

indata<-data.frame(var=c('Ä', 'Ö', 'ä', 'ö', 'ÄÄ_öö'))

write.table(indata, 'test.csv', sep=';', row.names = F, quote=F)

library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
library(dplyr)

db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="test") # Create empty database

RSQLite::dbWriteTable(conn = db, name = "testData", # Save csv into database
                  value = "test.csv",
                  row.names = FALSE, header = T, sep=';',
                  colClasses='character')

dbDisconnect(db)


con<-src_sqlite(path='test', create=F)

outdata<-collect(tbl(con, 'testData'))

outdata2<-read.csv('test.csv')

outdata # mangled umlauts
outdata2 # correct umlauts
```

How to have RSQLite preserve the umlauts?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Finnish_Finland.1252  LC_CTYPE=Finnish_Finland.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Finnish_Finland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
[5] LC_TIME=Finnish_Finland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.5.0   RSQLite_1.1-2 DBI_0.5-1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5   R6_2.2.0       assertthat_0.1 tools_3.3.2    tibble_1.2     memoise_1.0.0 
[7] Rcpp_0.12.9    digest_0.6.12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The large file you have is probably encoded in Latin-1, but it needs to be in UTF-8 to be processed correctly by RSQLite's CSV import. Adapt your example to use `write.table(..., fileEncoding = "UTF-8")` to double-check. (Note that Windows doesn't have UTF-8 encoding by default, most other OSs like Linux and OS X usually do, so the example you gave would work on Linux and OS X.)

Use `iconv` or `recode` to change the encoding of your file:

```
iconv -f latin1 in.csv > out.csv # creates new file
recode latin1..utf-8 file.csv    # in-place recoding
```

Comment: Thank you! Modifying the csv export command as:

`write.table(indata, 'test.csv', sep=';', row.names = F, quote=F, fileEncoding='UTF-8')`

displays Ä and Ö correctly when querying the RSQLite database based on the csv. However, it still produces `\r` as an end-of-line character in the final results. So I get `Ä\r` instead of `Ä`. How should the database be advised to drop the eol characters from the final output?

Comment: You'll need to write to a binary connection on Windows: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-December/263786.html

Answer (score 1):

Is writing to SQLite from the R dataframe object rather than from the csv file an option?

If it is, this works for me:

```
RSQLite::dbWriteTable(conn = db, name = "testData", 
                      value = indata,
                      row.names = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE)
```

(or the exact same workaround using the csv file name:

```
RSQLite::dbWriteTable(conn = db, name = "testData",
                      value = read.csv2("test.csv"),
                      row.names = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: No, the file is too large for RAM.